# Multiplying two numbers parallely

Tags: python

I have very large two numbers with same length and i want to multiply it parallely.

```
 e.g.: 1.  [45631] * [10011] = [40031]

       2.[6993123] * [1111000] = [6993000]
```

I did this using for loops.

```
p = input()
q = input()
for i in range(len(p)):
    print(int(p[i])*int(q[i]),end='')
```

But i stucked because of timeout. Is there a way to do this in O(1) complexity?

Comment: what if you have `44` * `44`, what do you expect?

Comment: It's pretty clear what he's asking.  He wants an O(1) complexity to solve the above.

Comment: I don't see how the above snippet multiplies big numbers. I just multiplies digit per digit.

Comment: No matter if java or python

Comment: One of number would consist of 1s and 0s.

Comment: So your problem is that your code crashes with very large numbers, and your solution is to find an algorithm with O(1) complexity.  Is this correct?

Comment: So in other words, you have two Strings, not numbers, one being a "mask" of 1 and 0 and you want to apply that mask the the other string?

Comment: @Nick Ziebert, you are correct.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but Integer Multiplication can not be performed in O(1) complexity, the theoretical bound is O(n log n). Not sure how you could implement parallelism to the multiplication problem. http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/cl/WS2007-8/mult.pdf

Comment: Yeah, i highly doubt this is possible with O(1) complexity.  I think you should pursue a different strategy.

Comment: At least O(log(n)) ???

Comment: What your really doing is performing an O(1) algorithm n times.  There is no escaping the need to look at each element.  You should come up with a way to split up the algorithm some way.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most beautiful code:

```
def split(num):
    return [int(n) for n in list(str(num))]

def multi(num1, num2):
    return [a*b for a,b in zip(split(num1),split(num2))]

def mainfoo(num1, num2):
    return int("".join([str(num) for num in multi(num1,num2)]))
```

And if we use it:

```
>>> mainfoo(45631, 10011) 
40031
>>> mainfoo(6993123, 1111000)
6993000
```

Comment: But is this O(1) complexity?

Comment: Same question arised.

Comment: @Cosmics : Given that numbers by their nature are binary and not base 10, I don't think that a solution that's less complex is possible.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, "[One of number would consist of 1s and 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664337/multiplying-two-numbers-parallely/41664665#comment70527440_41664337)", it seems like you do not want to "multiply large numbers" at all, but just mask one string with another, consisting of "1" and "0". You do not have to convert to `int` and multiply for that, and you don't have to use `print` in a loop. Try this instead:

```
>>> p, q = "6993123", "1111000"
>>> ''.join(c if b == "1" else "0" for c, b in zip(p, q))
'6993000'
```

This should be *much* faster then your code, but it is not O(1). Since you have n different characters to check in the string, there is no way to do this in less then O(n), even with parallelization (unless you have n cores).

---

For reference, here a performance comparison agains pairwise multiplication of digits:

```
>>> %timeit ''.join(str(int(x) * int(y)) for x, y in zip(p, q))
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.6 us per loop
>>> %timeit ''.join(c if b == "1" else "0" for c, b in zip(p, q))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.32 us per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get a timeout, I suppose the lists are large, not the numbers...

If you are in `python`, consider using [numpy.multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html).